$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ of degrees $m$ and $n$, $\gcd(m,n)=1$, $g(x)$ is irreducible in $F(\alpha)[x]$
Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$ of degrees $m$ and $n$, respectively where $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Show that if $\alpha$ is a root of $f(x)$ in some field extension of $F$, then $g(x)$ is irreducible in $F(\alpha)[x]$.
I think this relies on the tower law for fields. Let $\beta$ be a root of $g(x)$. Since $g(x)$ is irreducible over $F$, any root $\beta$ of $g(x)$ generates an extension $F(\beta)$ of degree $n$ over $F$. Consider now the composite field $F(\alpha)F(\beta)$. Because $\gcd(m,n)=1$, we can be sure that $[F(\alpha)F(\beta):F] = mn$. But now
$$mn = [F(\alpha)F(\beta):F] = [F(\alpha)F(\beta):F(\alpha)]\underbrace{[F(\alpha):F]}_m$$
This forces $[F(\alpha)F(\beta):F(\alpha)]  = n$; hence, the action of adjoining $\beta$ to $F(\alpha)$ has "the same effect" as adjoining $\beta$ to $F$. Arriving at this conclusion, some would say intuitively this shows that $g(x)$ must be irreducible over $F(\alpha)[x]$. But I want to show this via the definition of reducibility.
BWOC, suppose $g(x)$ was reducible over $F(\alpha)[x]$. Then we could write $g(x)=p(x)q(x)$ where $p(x),q(x) \in F(\alpha)[x]$ and are non-constant. $^\star$ Then $g(x)$ has a root $\gamma \in F(\alpha) \setminus F$; in particular, $F(\gamma) \subseteq F(\alpha)$. Since $\gamma \not\in F$, then $[F(\gamma):F] \geq 2$. But then
$$mn = [F(\alpha)F(\beta):F] = [F(\alpha)F(\beta):F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F(\gamma)]\underbrace{[F(\gamma):F]}_2 \hspace{3cm} (\star\star)$$
But now I am in doubt of $\star$, i.e. the implication that $g(x)$ being reducible over $F(\alpha)[x]$ means that $g(x)$ has a root in $F(\alpha)$; I know in general that reducibility does not at all imply existence of a root, but here it seems like having a root is the only way you could cut $g(x)$ into smaller pieces (how else would you even do it? every polynomial can be written as a product of linear factors).
And I'm also in doubt of $(\star\star)$, not because I think it is incorrect, but because all it shows is that $2$ divides $mn$, but not necessarily both of $m$ and $n$. How can I better address these two concerns?

The claim $(\star)$ that $g$ must have a root in $F(\alpha)$ is false. And while every polynomial can be written as a product of linear factors in some extension field, you are trying to claim it in a particular extension field, and that is not valid.
Instead, suppose $g(x) = p(x)q(x)$ in $F(\alpha)[x]$, with $0\lt\deg(p),\deg(q)\lt n$, and without loss of generality assume $p(x)$ is irreducible (factor $g(x)$ into irreducibles in $F(\alpha)[x]$, and let $p(x)$ be one of them and $q(x)$ be the product of the rest). Then we can construct an extension of $F(\alpha)$ by a root $\gamma$ of $p(x)$ to obtain an extension $F(\alpha)(\gamma)$, with $[F(\alpha)(\gamma):F(\alpha)]=\deg(p)\lt n$.
You can do a direct proof: let $p(x)$ be an irreducible factor of $g$ in $F(\alpha)$ and proceed as above. Then you get that $mn=\deg(p)m$, so we conclude that $\deg(p)=n=\deg(g)$, and hence that the irreducible factor $p(x)$ of $g(x)$ is equal to $g(x)$ (up to a unit); i.e., that $g$ is irreducible in $F(\alpha)$.
But $\gamma$ is also a root of $g$; you have shown that if $\beta$ is any root of $g$, then $[F(\alpha,\beta):F]=mn$. But taking $\gamma=\beta$, we have
$$mn = [F(\alpha,\gamma):F] = [F(\alpha)(\gamma):F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F] = \deg(p)m \lt mn,$$
which is impossible.
$(\star\star)$ is also incorrect. You have argued (incorrectly, but let that pass) that $[F(\gamma):F]\geq 2$. Then you turned this inequality into an equality with absolutely no warrant. You only have that $$[F(\alpha,\beta):F]\geq [F(\alpha,\beta):F(\alpha)][F(\alpha):F(\gamma)]2,$$ not equality.
In any case, it is easy to verify that $g(x)$ can have no root in $F(\alpha)$ unless it has degree $1$. For if $g(x)$ had a root $\beta$ in $F(\alpha)$, then we would have $F\subseteq F(\beta)\subseteq F(\alpha)$, and then you have
$$m = [F(\alpha):F] = [F(\alpha):F(\beta)][F(\beta):F] = n[F(\alpha):F(\beta)].$$
That means that $n\mid m$; but then $1=\gcd(n,m)=n$, so $g(x)$ is of degree $1$.

Your first claim regarding $g(x)$ having a root in $F (\alpha)$ is not true because here is the definition of irreducible element in any I.D:-
Suppose R is an I.D and $r \in R$ is a non zero and non-unit then $r$ is called irreducible in R if whenever $r=ab$ with $a,b \in $ R then either $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

Take a(x) =$(x^2+1)^3$ in $\mathbb{R[x]}$, it is reducible over $\mathbb{R}$ but has no root in $\mathbb{R}$.

And for the question, suppose g(x) has a root say $\beta$ in $F(\alpha)$ then,
$ m=[F(\alpha):F]=[F(\alpha):F(\beta)][F(\beta):F] >[F(\beta):F]=n$ which tells that $m$ is a multiple of $n$ which is not true.
